# 'neo4j-import: command not found' with Neo4j 3.0.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I removed my old installation of Neo4j and installed 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

So far so good, but when I try to run the import tools, I get `neo4j-import: command not found`.

I know the install tools are safely installed. I'm flummoxed as to what the problem might be.

Do I need to set some kind of permissions on the tool? Right now things look a little fishy:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 lightdm nogroup 1793 May  5 16:44 neo4j-import`

but I don't want to go crazy changing things without at least some small idea of what the issue might be.

Comment: did you use the debian package or the tarball?

Comment: I used the tarball. Debian is impossible due to the Java 8 problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make sure `<neo4j>/bin` is part of your `PATH` env variable or use the direct path to call it.

Pretty strange that your `neo4j-import` file belongs to user `lightdm` and group `nogroup`. Consider to change that to the user running neo4j.

Comment: To follow up for anyone else who googles and finds themselves here: adding the directory to the PATH seemed to do the trick. I didn't have to mess around with permissions (yet?). Try `export PATH=$PATH:/.../neo4j-community-3.0.1/bin`